# How to read each integer from a text file in c++?

Tags: c++, text, fstream

The program stops working as it is not reading the text file properly.
The text file has the following content:

```
1 2 
1 3 
1 4 
2 4 
3 4 
0 0 
1 2 
3 2
```

I want to get two graphs from the text file and 0 0 separates the two.

Thanks in advance.

```
int main()
{
    ifstream file2;
    file2.open("ass3.txt");
    int i=1;
    int t1;
    int t2;
    file2>>t1>>t2;
    Graph* graph1;
    Vertex* u;
    Vertex* v;
    cout<<t1<<" "<<t2;//this is giving value -2 and some other random number.
    while(t1==0 && t2==0){
        if(t1==i){
            u=addVertex(t1);
            insert(u,graph1);
            i++;
        }
        if(t2==i){
            u=addVertex(t1);
            insert(u,graph1);
            i++;
        }
        *u = graph1->vertices[t1];
        *v = graph1->vertices[t2];
        addEdge(u, v, true);
        addEdge(v, u, false);
        file2>>t1>>t2;
    }
    Graph* graph2;
    i=0;
    while (!file2.eof()){
        file2>>t1>>t2;
        if(t1==i){
            u=addVertex(t1);
            insert(u,graph2);
            i++;
        }
        if(t2==i){
            u=addVertex(t1);
            insert(u,graph2);
            i++;
        }
        *u = graph1->vertices[t1];
        *v = graph1->vertices[t2];
        addEdge(u, v, true);
        addEdge(v, u, false);
    }
return 1;
}
```

Comment: So far you've given us a vauge description of the problem. Saying that the program's "not working" is not enough to understand what's wrong.

Comment: I've put a cout in the code and also written the output. If I could get any more specific I would have solved the problem by myself.

Comment: The goal is to make the question as clear and succint as possible. This includes reducing the size of your code to the simplest example possible that recreates the problem you describe. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Are you sure the file ass3.txt exists and is readable? Your code works for me. You can check that the file was open correctly by querying file2.rdstate() & std::ifstream::failbit == 0. When the file doesn't exist the call to file2 >> t1 >> t2 does indeed result in garbage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the wrong condition in the first while loop, try setting

```
while(t1!=0 && t2!=0){
```

instead of

```
while(t1==0 && t2==0){
```

With the condition you use, you immediatly hop to the 2nd loop and the entire file is put inside the 2nd graph, resulting in uninitialized values in the first one .

Hope this helps..

Comment: Thanks for telling me about that mistake but the same problem still persists

Comment: Then it may be a problem related to the graph functions, changing the condition the code seems to work fine for me (i removed the graph part which code you didn't post leaving only the file interaction, and debugging it it worked fine)

Comment: I removed all the code after cout and initialized t1 and t2 to be 0. Now it gives 0 0 as output, which means the file2>>t1>>t2; is not changing anything.

Comment: I found the problem, don't bother.

Comment: That's kinda weird, doing the same my output is `1 2` which is the correct first line of the file.
I'll go with some dumb questions then..are you sure that the file is in the right place, readable and so on..?